# How can I fix this if statement in my blackjack bust system?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, blackjack

I'm new to coding and working on an assignment for school. I'm coding blackjack with Java. This is probably an easy fix but my code does this

---

The dealers total is 7

Your total is 11

would you like another card?
y/n
y

---

Your total is 20
Would you like another card?
y/n
y

---

Your total is 26
Would you like another card?
y/n
y

---

Your total is 26
You went bust
You now have $400.0
Would you like to play again? y/n

.

The problem is that it gets higher than 21, but doesn't tell you that you went bust until the next loop. I'd like it to just say the last one instead of the 2nd to last and the last one.

```java
System.out.println("would you like another card? \ny/n");
answer = sanswer.nextLine();

//if player answers
while ("y".equals(answer)) {
    if (total < 21){
        hit = (int) Math.floor(Math. random() * 10) + 1;
        total += hit;
        System.out.println("____________________________\n");
        System.out.println("Your total is " + total);
        System.out.println("Would you like another card? \ny/n");
        answer = sanswer.nextLine();
    }  
    //player bust
    if (total > 21) {
        System.out.println("______________");
        System.out.println("Your total is " + total);
        System.out.println("You went bust");     
        System.out.println("You now have $" + money);
        play = "no";
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? y/n");
        answer = "";
        play = srplay.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean Java (not JavaScript)? The code provided is written in Java.

Comment: Yes I did my bad

Comment: Given that when you start the while loop the player has already committed to hit, perhaps adding the hit before checking would help.

Comment: I suggest that you print your value of `total` just after the line `while ("y".equals(answer)) {`. I think it will help you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this place:

```
total += hit;
```

At this point the total might exceed 21. Check this. Act based on the value:

```
if (total > 21) { /* do something here */ }
```